# How to add namespace to a specified element with cxf?

Tags: java, xml, cxf

I have a problem with cxf 3.0.1. When I send request to service, cxf takes namespace from @XmlRootElement annotation of my element and move it to the root element of the body.
Example:

Class A:

```
@XmlSeeAlso(value=B.class)
public class A{

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    protected Object any;
    //gettres and setters
}
```

Class B:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="B", namespace="http://elementBNamespace/")
public class B{
    //fields, getters and setters
}
```

When I send request it looks like so:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    ...
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-46f08307-9931-4494-a0a0-a87ae051d988">
    <ns3:rootElement
            xmlns:ns3="http://rootelementnamespace/"
            xmlns:ns4="http://namespace4/"
            xmlns:ns6="http://namespace6/"
            xmlns:ns7="http://elementBNamespace/">

     ...
        <ns4:A>
            <ns7:B>...<ns7:B>
        </ns4:A>
    </ns3:rootElement>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And what I need is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    ...
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-46f08307-9931-4494-a0a0-a87ae051d988">
    <ns3:rootElement
            xmlns:ns3="http://rootelementnamespace/"
            xmlns:ns4="http://namespace4/"
            xmlns:ns6="http://namespace6/">

     ...
        <ns4:A>
            <ns7:B xmlns:ns7="http://elementBNamespace/">...<ns7:B>
        </ns4:A>
    </ns3:rootElement>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I avoid this behaviour?
Thank you!

Comment: In the XML you posted the two forms are functionally identical.  If elementBNamespace is only used on a solitary "B" element, it doesn't need to appear anywhere else. Why do you feel the need to move that declaration up to a parent element?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the cxf transformation feature http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html. I think the section "Changing input and output element names and namespaces" from this site will help you.